# PJAX and jQuery ScrollTo conflict

Tags: jquery, scrollto, pjax

I have put together a simple site here: http://matt.srgunltd.co.uk/

It is built on Jekyll and uses PJAX to ajax-serve the content. On the homepage when the site first loads if you click "See what I do" it uses ScrollTo (https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) to move smoothly down to anchors in the page. Now if you visit the blog, then return to the homepage, this functionality is broken.

There appears to be some conflict between PJAX and ScrollTo but I can't figure out what it might be, as there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick events works on content that is loaded in DOM on page load.
When you visit other page i.e Blog The content gets updated dynamically.

You need to use `deligation` for your click events on dynamically generated content.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.overview-link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    jQuery('body').scrollTo('#overview',{duration:'slow', offset:-60});
})
```